# FormData no obtiene val de form

Tags: jquery, ajax, formdata

Quiero enviar información que quiero a un controlador pero al momento de picarle al botón de enviar, pongo el punto de interrupción en la función que tengo en el controlador y en las 2 variables de `Text` y `Contacto` que tengo, las obtengo como `null`.

```
function enviarInfo(e) {

        if (e.type == "submit") {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        var URL = '@Url.Action("ContactoDictamen", "ComoDatoDetalles")';

        var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

        var Id = $('#frmPdf input[name=Id]').val();
        var Text = $('#frmPdf textarea[name=Dictamen]').val();
        var Contacto = $('#frmPdf select[name=ContactoId]').val();

        console.log('text -> ' + Text);
        console.log('contacto -> ' + Contacto);

        formData.append("Id", Id);
        formData.append("Text", Text);
        formData.append("Contacto", Contacto);
        

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            url: URL,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            sucess: function (response) {
                Swal.fire('Enviado', response.responseText, 'success');
            }
        });

    }
```

Esta es la función con que envió la info al controlador

```
public ActionResult ContactoDictamen(int? id, string Text, int? Contacto)
        {
            try
            {
                if (id != null || Text != null || Contacto != null)
                {
                    return Print(id, Text, Contacto);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Enviado" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Error" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Los action por defaul reciben por método GET, a ti te falta indicar que ese `action` es por POST, de esta manera

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ContactoDictamen(int? id, string Text, int? Contacto)
{

}
```

También puedes probar colocando el nombre

```
[HttpPost("ContactoDictamen")]
public ActionResult ContactoDictamen(int? id, string Text, int? Contacto){

}
```

Comment: Ya lo tenía como el httpPost pero no me deja ponerle lo de las comillas, me da error que `'HttPostAttribute' no contiene un constructor que tome 1 argumentos.`